# John 6:45b - who is the everyone, the Jews or everyone comes to Jesus?

Tags: john, soteriology

1. What  "comes to me" means?
2. What does "has heard and learned from the Father" mean? Is it a prerequisite for everyone coming to Jesus?

Text: John 6:45b (ESV)
"-who has heard and learned from the Father comes to me."

Answer (score 3):

In John 6:45, Jesus quotes Isa 54:13 -

> Then all your sons will be taught by the LORD, and great will be their
> prosperity.

What is this discussing?  It is discussing a Jerusalem that is described thus (Isa 54:11-14 -

> **11** “O afflicted city, lashed by storms, without solace, surely I will set your stones in antimony and lay your foundations with
> sapphires.
>
> **12** I will make your pinnacles of rubies, your gates of sparkling jewels, and all your walls of precious stones.
>
> **13** *Then all your sons will be taught by the LORD, and great will be their prosperity*.
>
> **14** In righteousness you will be established, far from oppression, for you will have no fear. Terror will be far removed, for it will not
> come near you.

This is not the Jerusalem we know today - it is the New Jerusalem of Rev 21 & 22 with foundations made of jewels, a city founded on righteousness and completely free of terror!  Quite different from the present city of Jerusalem.

Therefore, When the NT says of this New Jerusalem,

> And they will all be taught by God.’ Everyone who has heard the Father
> and learned from Him comes to Me

The everyone must include all people who are taught by God, everyone who has heard the Father.  Not just Jews, but people from all nations (Ps 148:11, Gen 18;18, Ps 86:9, 72:11, 60:3, Isa 56:7, etc.)